# Dagger2: Component cannot depend on multiple scoped components

Tags: android, scope, named-scope, dagger-2

Yes, I know this has been asked before, and yes, I know it is "by design".

But I'd like to do something like this:

```
@Component(modules = {RealmModule.class})
public interface RealmComponent {
    Realm realm();
}


@Component(modules = {RepositoryModule.class})
public interface RepositoryComponent {
    PersonRepository personRepository();

    ScheduleRepository schedulesRepository();
}

@Component(dependencies = {RealmComponent.class, RepositoryComponent.class})
public interface AppDataComponent
        extends RealmComponent, RepositoryComponent {
}

@ApplicationScope
@Component(dependencies = {AppContextComponent.class,
        AppDataComponent.class,
        AppDomainComponent.class,
        AppPresentationComponent.class,
        AppUtilsComponent.class})
public interface ApplicationComponent
        extends AppContextComponent, AppDataComponent, AppDomainComponent, AppUtilsComponent, AppPresentationComponent {
    void inject(CustomApplication customApplication);

    void inject(DashboardActivity dashboardActivity);
}
```

However, what I get is **unscoped**, every time I inject a `JobManager` or a `ScheduleRepository` or anything else, **I get a new instance**. The only way I could "fix" that was this.

```
@Module
public class JobManagerModule {
    private JobManager jobManager;

    @Provides
    public JobManager jobManager(Context context) {
        if(jobManager == null) {
            jobManager = new JobManager(context, new Configuration.Builder(context).networkUtil(
                    new WifiOrMobileNetworkUtil(context)).build());
        }
        return jobManager;
    }
}
```

Not a fan.

So, how is one meant to structure and rip apart the dependency tree, **without** making one big gigantic über blob component that has *every single module* listed and *every single provision method* (instead of these "subcomponent" component dependencies)?

I tried using subcomponents for this, but then you have to provide every single module for the final `ApplicationComponent`.

I'm not sure what to do here. I tried specifying `@Singleton` for every first-level component and `@SubcomponentScope` for every `AppDataLevelComponent`, I also tried making a new scope for every single subcomponent, but both of them failed with "cannot depend on multiple scoped components".

**EDIT:** Apparently in order to get scoped providers, marking the components with the scope is not enough - you must specify the scope for the `@Provides` annotated methods too.

```
@Module
public class RepositoryModule {
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    public PersonRepository personRepository() {
        return new PersonRepositoryImpl();
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    public ScheduleRepository schedulesRepository() {
        return new SchedulesRepositoryImpl();
    }
}
```

In the meantime, I ended up with this übercomponent.

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = {
        AppContextModule.class,
        DbMapperModule.class,
        DbTaskModule.class,
        RealmModule.class,
        RepositoryModule.class,
        InteractorModule.class,
        ServiceModule.class,
        PresenterModule.class,
        XmlPersisterModule.class
})
public interface ApplicationComponent
        extends AppContextComponent, AppDataComponent, AppDomainComponent, AppUtilsComponent, AppPresentationComponent {
```

Where the `xyzComponent` classes are just interfaces to store the provision methods...

(**Please note that** [this structure is an anti-pattern as described by Martin Fowler, and you should organize modules based on features / activities](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/PresentationDomainDataLayering.html), and make them into subscoped components using component dependencies. Component dependencies are used to subscope your superscope components, and "inherit" dependency providers.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had same problems like you not while ago and ended using the same ubercomponent approach except I use `@Subcomponent`s in order organize the things and not to have all modules listed in the ubercomponent (I call it "top" or "app's" component).

You may see an example here:
[How to migrate missing inject from module with complete = false from Dagger 1 to Dagger 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31354735/how-to-migrate-missing-inject-from-module-with-complete-false-from-dagger-1-to)