# Dependency Injection With Dagger 2

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger-2

I'm trying to create an Android library alongside another project whilst learning DI with Dagger 2. It's proving to be more difficult than expected.

**My Question**

I'm trying to use a singleton class called `MySingleton` that I want to access from both my Android library as well as the main application.

**Current Setup**

Basically I have a singleton class called `MySingleton` in my Android library project. In the project I have a class called `SingletonModule` which is a Dagger2 module that provides my singleton like so.

```
@Provides @Singleton
MySingleton providesMySingleton() {
    return new MySingleton();
}
```

Ok, now in my actual application in I have the following component.

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = {SingletonModule.class})
public interface ApplicationComponent {
    void inject( MyApplication application );
}
```

So this is used to inject `MySingleton` into the `MyApplication` class. It does it like so.

```
this.applicationComponent = DaggerApplicationComponent.builder()
            .singletonModule( new SingletonModule() ) // does it for you as empty constructor
            .build();
    applicationComponent.inject(this);
```

This is great and the instance of `MySingleton` that I'm injecting by field is working fine.

**What I have Tried**

In my Android library project I created a new component called `SingletonComponent` which did the same as `ApplicationComponent`, just provided the `MySingleton` object. Then in the `MyService` class which extends `Service` I injected, by field, the `MySingleton` object. This did not have the effect I was after. It did object a `MySingleton` object but it was not the same instance as created when injecting into my actual application. I believe this is because it is a new component that I'm creating...

What am I doing wrong here?

I have looked on many different sites and followed many tutorials but something just isn't clicking with this dependency injection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I believe this is because it is a new component that I'm creating...

You are absolutely correct. Singletons are unique per dependency graph. When creating second component you are essentially creating second dependency graph which have different object for that singleton.

There are two solutions:

1. Create just one graph in your app that includes the lib modules
2. Create one graph in you lib, and then add your app module(s) to it (like in: https://github.com/google/dagger/tree/master/examples/android-activity-graphs (they are adding "per activity" module there but you will get the idea))

Comment: I need to be able to inject modules into classes in my library. What if I have a component that's created in my library (maybe some sort of singleton) that I then pass into my Application component that then uses that instance of it?

Comment: As far as I understand you you will need something like:
`@Component(dependencies = LibraryComponent.class, modules = MyAppModule.class)` for your application component. That way your application component will include the lib component and will be able to use its objects (which is basically the meaning of option 2).

Comment: I'm going to link your own question I just found that helped me solve it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31354735/how-to-migrate-missing-inject-from-module-with-complete-false-from-dagger-1-to This is exactly what I needed.